# How do I get a filehandle from the command line?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a subroutine that takes a filehandle as an argument.  How do I make a filehandle from a file path specified on the command line?  I don't want to do any processing of this file myself, I just want to pass it off to this other subroutine, which returns an array of hashes with all the parsed data from the file.

Here's what the command line input I'm using looks like:

`$ ./getfile.pl /path/to/some/file.csv`

Here's what the beginning of the subroutine I'm calling looks like:

```
sub parse {
    my $handle = shift;
    my @data   = <$handle>;
    while (my $line = shift(@data)) {
      # do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a file handle, you have a file *name*. Which does the subroutine expect?

Comment: i've updated the question per your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Command line arguments are available in the predefined `@ARGV` array. You can get the file name from there and use `open` to open a filehandle to it. Assuming that you want read-only access to the file, you would do it this way:

```
my $file = shift @ARGV;
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
parse($fh);
```

Note that the `or die...` checks the call `open` for success and dies with an error message if it wasn't. The built-in variable `$!` will contain the (OS dependent) error message on failure that tells you why the call wasn't successful. e.g. "Permission denied."

Comment: You could also `use autodie;` to avoid having to check the `open` call for success manually. Currently you have to install autodie from the CPAN, but it’s probably going to be shipped with Perl as of 5.10.1.

Answer (score 5):

`parse(*ARGV)` is the simplest solution: the explanation is a bit long, but an important part of learning how to use Perl effectively is to learn Perl.

When you use a null filehandle (`<>`), it actually reads from the magical `ARGV` filehandle, which has special semantics: it reads from all the files named in `@ARGV`, or `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty.

From `perldoc perlop`:

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the
>   behavior of sed and awk.  Input from `<>` comes either from standard
>   input, or from each file listed on the command line.  Here’s how it
>   works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and
>   if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened gives you
>   standard input.  The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of
>   filenames.  The loop
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>     ...                     # code for each line
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
> unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
> while ($ARGV = shift) {
>     open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>     while (<ARGV>) {
>         ...         # code for each line
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> except that it isn’t so cumbersome to say, and will actually work.  It
>   really does shift the `@ARGV` array and put the current filename into the
>   `$ARGV` variable.  It also uses filehandle `ARGV` internally--`<>` is just a
>   synonym for `<ARGV>`, which is magical.  (The pseudo code above doesn’t
>   work because it treats `<ARGV>` as non-magical.)

You don't have to use `<>` in a `while` loop -- `my $data = <>` will read one line from the first non-empty file, `my @data = <>;` will slurp it all up at once, and you can pass `*ARGV` around as if it were a normal filehandle.

Comment: It doesn't quite answer the question directly... but suggesting, based on this, that the OP pass the ARGV filehandle to his function would.  (Assuming, of course, that doing so would work - I haven't tried it.)

Comment: Clarified this answer to say that parse(*ARGV) does work, instead of putting it in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the -n switch is for!

Take your parse method, and do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

#do stuff
```

Each line is stored in $_. So you run

./getfile.pl /path/to.csv

And it does this.

See [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/08/09/commandline.html?page=2) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for some more info about these. I like -p too, and have found the combo of -a and -F to be really useful.

Also, if you want to do some extra processing, add BEGIN and end blocks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

BEGIN {
  my $accumulator;
}

# do stuff

END {
  print process_total($accumulator);
}
```

or whatever. This is very, very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something or are you just looking for the open() call?

```
open($fh, "<$ARGV[0]") or die "couldn't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
do_something_with_fh($fh);
close($fh);
```

Comment: This is wrong. It's open my $fh, "<$ARGV[0]". The $fh is the first argument, not the return value! (or better yet open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0].